# How to rank values of list in r?

Tags: r, list

So I'd like to rank values of list in R regardless of the separation.

```
l <- list(x = c(2.5,3.4,4.3,3.0), y = c(0,4.1,5.9))
```

I'd like to get a list of each element position's when sorted without taking into account the division like :

```
r <- list(x= c(2,4,6,3), y = c(1,5,7))
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option where we `unlist` the `list`, `rank` it and `relist` by specifying the `skeleton` from 'l'

```
relist(rank(unlist(l)), skeleton = l)
```

---

Or with `split`

```
split(rank(unlist(l, use.names = FALSE)), rep(names(l), lengths(l)))
```